# Cannot import name 'RadioChoiceInput' from 'django.forms.widgets' (Django 1.19 to 3.2 migration)

Tags: python, html, django

I have the following widgets.py file from a Django 1.19 version to upgrade to Djando 3.2 version.

I am getting the error:

```
from django.forms.widgets import RadioSelect, RadioChoiceInput
ImportError: cannot import name 'RadioChoiceInput' from 'django.forms.widgets' (my_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py)
```

This is the code:

```
from django.forms.widgets import RadioFieldRenderer, RadioChoiceInput

class RadioChoiceInput2(RadioChoiceInput):
    def render(self, name=None, value=None, attrs=None, choices=()):
        # locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')
        if self.id_for_label:
            label_for = format_html(' for="{}"', self.id_for_label)
        else:
            label_for = ''
        attrs = dict(self.attrs, **attrs) if attrs else self.attrs
        try:
            self.choice_label = locale.format("%.2f", float(self.choice_label), grouping=True)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        return format_html(
                '<label class="radio" {}>{} <i></i> {}</label>', label_for,
                self.tag(attrs), self.choice_label
        )

class RadioFieldRenderer2(RadioFieldRenderer):
    outer_html = '{content}'
    inner_html = '<section class="col col-2">{choice_value}{sub_widgets}' \
                 '<i></i></section>'
    last_inner_html = '<section class="col col-1 last">{choice_value}{sub_widgets}' \
                      '<i></i></section>'

    choice_input_class = RadioChoiceInput2

    def render(self):

        id_ = self.attrs.get('id')
        output = []
        cc = len(self.choices)
        for i, choice in enumerate(self.choices):
            choice_value, choice_label = choice
            if isinstance(choice_label, (tuple, list)):
                attrs_plus = self.attrs.copy()
                if id_:
                    attrs_plus['id'] += '_{}'.format(i)
                sub_ul_renderer = self.__class__(
                        name=self.name,
                        value=self.value,
                        attrs=attrs_plus,
                        choices=choice_label,
                )

                ih = self.inner_html
                if i == 2:
                    ih = self.last_inner_html

                sub_ul_renderer.choice_input_class = self.choice_input_class
                output.append(format_html(ih, choice_value=choice_value,
                                          sub_widgets=sub_ul_renderer.render()))
            else:
                ih = self.inner_html
                if i == cc-1:
                    ih = self.last_inner_html
                w = self.choice_input_class(self.name, self.value,
                                            self.attrs.copy(), choice, i)
                output.append(ih.format(
                        choice_value=force_text(w),
                        sub_widgets='')
                )

        return format_html(self.outer_html,
                           id_attr=format_html(' id="{}"', id_) if id_ else '',
                           content=mark_safe('\n'.join(output)))


class OrderRadioSelectWidget(RadioSelect):
    renderer = RadioFieldRenderer2
```

But I don't found any documentation or way to replace this part of code, how migrate this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe `RadioChoiceInput` was replaced by [`RadioSelect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/widgets/#radioselect). I would start by looking at the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/forms/widgets.py#L760) there and figuring out what you need to change from your existing overrides.